# Shell script updating same file code is looping through

Tags: shell

The below code is currently working to update a property file with values from set environment variables. However, I'm wondering **are there any issues/problems with updating the same file the code is looping through (at the same time)?** https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2094

The below code:

1. Loops through each line of a property file
2. Finds the `key=value` pair
3. Converts the `key` property to an `ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` name
4. Updates the same file with the new value from the `ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` so that now -- > `key=ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE`

**Before code is run:**
MY_COLOR_PROP=yellow
my.color.prop=red

**After code is run:**
my.color.prop=yellow

```
FILE_NAME="./path/to/folder/my-app-${ENV}.properties"
echo "Update $FILE_NAME..."
OIFS=$IFS
while IFS="=" read -r key value; do
  case "$key" in
  '#'*)
    echo "Skipping comment line..."
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Property from file: $key=$value"
    ENV_VAR=$(echo "$key" | sed 's/\./_/g' | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
    ENV_VAR_VALUE=$(printf '%s\n' "${!ENV_VAR}")
    echo "Environment variable: $ENV_VAR=$ENV_VAR_VALUE"
    if [ -n "$ENV_VAR_VALUE" ]; then
      echo "Setting $key=$ENV_VAR_VALUE in $FILE_NAME..."
      sed -i "/$key=/ s^=.*^=$ENV_VAR_VALUE^" "$FILE_NAME"
    else
      echo "Skipping $key property - No value set for $ENV_VAR..."
    fi
    ;;
  esac
done <"$FILE_NAME"
IFS=$OIFS
```

***** UPDATE with what I implemented from below answer *****
My property file has comments in it and only a subset of the properties will need to be updated, the rest should remain untouched.

```
input="path/to/file/my.properties"

while IFS="=" read -r key value; do
  case "$key" in
  '#'*)
    echo "$key"
    ;;
  *)
    ENV_VAR=$(echo "$key" | sed 's/\./_/g' | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]')
    echo "$key"="${!ENV_VAR-$value}"
    ;;
  esac
done < "$input" > tmp; mv tmp "$input"
```

where the `my.properties` file looks like...

```
# Comment number one
bob=tom
organization.name=Chris Peter Org
# Comment number two
# Comment number three
db.url=jdbc:mysql://dburl/dbname
# Comment number four
test.parameter.ccf=always
```

Comment: Yes, there are issues.  Just replace the `sed -i` with `sed` and do `while read ... done < $FILE_NAME > tmp; mv tmp $FILE_NAME`  There is absolutely no benefit to mutating the file as you process it.

Comment: Put  your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/, you will see roughly the same message than what @WilliamPursell mentionned.

Comment: Thank you both very much, your comments and the shellcheck.net site were extremely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
while IFS== read k v ; do echo $k=${!k-$v}; done < input > tmp && mv tmp input
```

eg:

```
$ cat input
foo=bar
baz=qux
$ unset baz
$ foo=foovalue
$ while IFS== read k v ; do echo $k=${!k-$v}; done < input > tmp && mv tmp input
$ cat input
foo=foovalue
baz=qux
```

Note that `$!{k}` is a bashism, and if you're not using bash you might want to do something like:

```
while IFS== read k v ; do eval echo \$k=\${$k:-$v}; done < input
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I think I was able to correctly implement your suggestions.